# regex to replace numbers separated by either space or a tab

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I have rows of data that look like:

```
12   1234   6
33   154    10
1734  2345  7
```

I am trying to create a regex in VS Code to use as a search and replace where I can use $1 $2 $3 in the replace to represent the different numbers in the line

So that I can replace it with something like

```
(12) [1234] {6}
(33) [154]  {7}
```

I am not sure how to match it so it captures all 3 numbers in one regex split out into the separate numbers

(\d+) is matching each number individually, but how do I get it to match all 3 numbers in $1 $2 $3 ?

Comment: `^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$` => `($1) [$2] {$3}`.

Comment: Is it important to maintain the spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code, you can use

```js
Find what:    ^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$
Replace with: ($1) [$2] {$3}
```

Or, if you need to keep the same whitespace amount between the numebrs:

```js
Find what:    ^(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)$
Replace with: ($1)$2[$3]$4{$5}
```

NOTE: the `\s` shorthand character class usually matches line breaks, but in Visual Studio Code, when the pattern has no `\r` nor `\n`, `\s` does not match line breaks, so it is safe to use it, as it won't match across lines.

If you strictly need to only match lines with digit sequences separated with space/tabs, then replace `\s+` with `[ \t]+`.

See the demo:

[image]